# How to copy posts from one site to another in real time (not multisite)

Tags: posts, post-duplication

I'm working to rebrand my company's website (new look, URL, etc.).  I've already transferred all of the existing posts, pages, users, media from site B (old) to site A (new) and I have site A up and running for me to design around now.

**My question is this:**
Is there a way that when a user publishes a post on site B that it can also create that post on site A, so when I eventually deactivate site B all of the posts, images, etc. on site A will be current?

I've searched around a bit and I see there are articles on how to perform this within a multisite, but we are using two individual installs.  I've also seen RSS methods or plugins, but those seem to be more of a feed, rather than creating actual database entries in the new database.

Comment: https://distributorplugin.com/ might be of help if you haven't checked that out already. It's quite a tricky problem so it's best to use already existing solutions. Of course this plugin isn't the only one.